AVX Instruction Set is Missing on Ubuntu 24.04
Both servers have identical hardware specifications, including CPUs. One is running Ubuntu 22.04, while the other is running 24.04.
Here is the lscpu output from the server running 22.04:
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6278C CPU @ 2.60GHz
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                85
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   16
    Socket(s):            2
    Stepping:             7
    BogoMIPS:             5200.00
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush 
                          mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl 
                          xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 
                          sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor 
                          lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced 
                          fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f avx512dq 
                          rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 
                          arat avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities

And here is the lscpu output from the server running 24.04:
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  Model name:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6278C CPU @ 2.60GHz
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                85
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   16
    Socket(s):            2
    Stepping:             7
    BogoMIPS:             5200.00
    Flags:                fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush 
                          mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl 
                          xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 pcid sse4_1
                          sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm 
                          abm 3 dnowprefetch ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 
                          smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb arat md_clear flush_l1d
                          arch_capabilities

The AVX is absent on Ubuntu 24.04. Additionally, 24.04 was not freshly installed but upgraded from 22.04, so the issue is not due to missing packages.
As noted here, I also attempted to install libmkl-dev libmkl-avx2, but it didn't resolve the issue for me.
